# Bootstrap Datepicker AngularJS model Invalid format

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap Datepicker with AngularJS. When I select the date, the selected date format is MM/dd/yyyy but when I access the $scope model, it shows MMddyyyy. I could not understand why it is removing '/' from the date. I want to parse the MM/dd/yyyy into yyyy-MM-dd

here is html code:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" id="startDate" maxlength="10" placeholder="Start Date" ui-mask="99/99/9999" datepicker="" name="startDate" ng-model="startDateCalendar.startDate" ng-style="ProviderDetail.HexColorCode !== undefined ? {'border-color': ProviderDetail.HexColorCode } : {'border-color': '#4e4e4e'}" class="wid89 dPicker"
                               data-ng-click="startDateCalendar.open($event)" />
                        <i class="calender-icon-pos fa fa-calendar" ng-click="openDetapicker('startDate')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
```

And here is javascript model object:

```
 $scope.startDateCalendar = {
            startDate: "",
            formats: ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'],
            format: 'shortDate',
            dateOptions: {
                formatYear: 'yy',
                startingDay: 1,
                showWeeks: 'false'
            },
            open: function ($event) {
                $event.preventDefault();
                $event.stopPropagation();
                $scope.startDateCalendar.status.opened = !$scope.startDateCalendar.status.opened;
            },
            status: {
                opened: false
            },
        };
```

and here is openDatePicker function for calendar icon.

```
$scope.openDetapicker = function (ctrlId) {
            $("#" + ctrlId).datepicker().focus();
        }
```

Comment: can you please post your code? your html code on how you show the datepicker, your input handler code, how you set the ``$scope`` variable etc..

Comment: @henokg I have updated the question